# Exclusive access to dynamic shared data

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm looking for the best way to ensure exclusive access to **dynamic** shared data, where:

- "**dynamic**" means that data (instances of some class) will be dynamically created and deleted throughout the application lifetime. It must be possible to do so safely without causing undefined behaviour or accessing invalid memory.
- "exclusive access to ... shared data" means that these instances will be accessed by multiple threads but only one thread will be allowed to operate on the object at any given time.

What I have in mind so far is a solution that involves a class for storing instances of objects and providing access to them in a way that satisfies above requirements:

1. Object instances can be added to the storage class, which will make them "visible" to all threads. Actual object construction is out of scope.
2. After `get`-ing some object, no other thread can `get` it until the first thread has confirmed that it is done using the object (unlocked it)
3. After object has been removed from the storage, a) no other thread can obtain or b) still hold the pointer obtained via `get`. **Part B of this requirement is optional.** This is to ensure that object can be safely destroyed after being removed from storage. Actual object destruction is out of scope.

One way I could think of to satisfy above requirements is by using 1 "global" RW-lock and 1 mutex per object arranged in the following way (pseudocode):

```
class ExclusiveAccessMap {
    private:
        g Lock;      // readers-writer lock
        dataMap Map;

    public:
        void add(MyClass o) {
            write_lock(g);
            dataMap[o.id] = o;
            unlock(g);
        }

        MyClass get(String id) {
            read_lock(g);
            o = dataMap[id];    // omitting existance checks
            o.lock();           // Caller assumes responsibility of unlocking object when it's done with it
            unlock(g);

            return o;
        }

        void remove(String id) {
            write_lock(g);
            o = dataMap[id];    // omitting existance checks
            o.lock();           
            o.unlock(l);
            del dataMap[id];
            unlock(g);
        }
}
```

Things that I am aware of that could be improved:

- when getting stored object, locking and unlocking is done in 2 separate places.
- when deleting any object, ALL readers will be blocked and not just the ones trying to read the object to be deleted.

My questions are:

1. Are there any other (more critical) issues with the above approach?
2. Can any of the 2 issues listed above be improved?
3. Is there some fundamentally different way to go about ensuring exclusive access to dynamic shared data?

Comment: In the `get` method calling `o.lock()` with `g` lock taken (before `unlock(g)`) eliminates almost all benefits from two locks: while a reader waits for some object being accessible, no further readers could succeed in getting an (other) object. The `remove` method suffers from the same problem. What do you expect from `remove` method when it is called concurrently with the reader of the same object? Should it immediately remove reference to the object from the map but wait for the reader before deleting the object itself?

Comment: @Tsyvarev notice that `get` method is obtaining a read-lock on `g`, so multiple other readers will be able to concurrently execute `get` as long as they don't try to access the same object.

Comment: @Tsyvarev as for expected behaviour of `remove`, that would depend on how read-write lock implementation will treat this particular situation and who (reader or writer(deleter)) will get to go first. If reader gets priority, then `delete` execution will have to wait until object will be manually unlocked (see comment in the code). If writer goes first, then `get` will not be able to return the object. I don't have very strong requirements in terms of reader/writer priority, I'm just trying to ensure that after `remove` is executed, no other thread can obtain pointer to removed object via `get`

Comment: @Tsyvarev P.S. sorry if my pseudo-code format confused you. I'm not that comfortable with C++ to write close-to-valid code "on paper" and I wanted to avoid people getting sucked into any "implementation" mistakes I might have made. Hence the pseudo-code above to help keep the conversation at the level of ideas and principles.

Comment: "I'm just trying to ensure that after `remove` is executed, no other thread can obtain pointer to removed object via `get`" - While this requirement could be seen as imprecise, it is actually an important requirement. Currently your post describes only requirements to `get`, and does not describe `remove`. But most of your problems are from `remove`. For resolve these problems we need requirements for `remove`: please, add them (copy them from your comments) into the **question post** itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've updated the question with your suggestion. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, the question have become much more specific. I had some ideas how to fulfil the first part of the 3d requirement - "After object has been removed from the storage, no other thread can obtain a pointer via `get`". In that idea the object is destroyed by the last user of that object (either by a writer or by a reader). But that idea conflicts with the second part of the requirement - "After object has been removed from the storage, no other thread can still hold the pointer obtained via `get`". Of course, that doesn't mean that the requirement is wrong... But are you sure you need it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev "But are you sure you need it?" - great question! After thinking it through I have to admit that it's not a requirement, but rather me trying to abuse the requirement for the purpose of steering the solution. It just seems easier to reason about the code where `remove` has a more "absolute" semantic. But like I said, it's true it's not strictly necessary. After all, it can probably be worked around fairly easily by checking if object is still in storage after obtaining lock on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

- have a mutex associated with each object,
- keep each object in a smart pointer,
- keep smart pointers in some concurrent map (e.g. Intel's TBB one).

Usage:

- someone gets the pointer from the map (safe),
- while holding a smart pointer reference to the object tries to lock the mutex (safe),
- uses the object and subsequently releases the lock (safe),
- disposes the local smart pointer copy (safe).

When it's time to delete the object:

- you remove it from the map (safe),
- the object is destroyed after the last reference to it is disposed of (safe).